Getting coloured boxes with OhMyZsh

Hi,
Why am I getting this colored area with OhMyZsh on MAC?
The Font is Hack Nerd.
The "Display ANSI colors" checkbox in the terminal settings affects this.
If I uncheck it the colours are gone.
I have tried:

source ~/.zshrc
omz reload
Random theme

but none of them seem to have any effect on this.
